# "Nothing found to display" error in display-tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts, displaytag

Following is my code to display rows using `display-tag` in `struts 1.3` but it always shows: `Nothing found to display`. I have checked `ResultSet` and `ArrayList` object, they all contain data.

```
<display:table export="true" id="data"
            name="sessionScope.MultipleStudentsDAO.studentList"
            requestURI="/mssrv.do" pagesize="5">

            <display:column property="rollNo" title="ROLL NO" sortable="true" />
            <display:column property="name" title="NAME" sortable="true" />
            <display:column property="branch" title="BRANCH" sortable="false" />

</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sessionScope.MultipleStudentsDAO.studentList` in the `name` attribute, `display:table` will be looking in the `session` for an object called `MultipleStudentsDAO` and then calling its `studentList` property. For this to work you should be doing something like this in your Java code:

```
MultipleStudentsDAO yourVariableOfTypeMultipleStudentsDAO = ...
session.setAttribute("MultipleStudentsDAO", yourVariableOfTypeMultipleStudentsDAO);
```

Note that `MultipleStudentsDAO` is the name I have given the `session` attribute and not necessarily the name of the class (although they happen to be the same in this case to make your JSP code work).

As an aside, I would advise against storing an attribute in the `session` unless there is a particular reason why you need to - put it in the request instead, for example:

```
MultipleStudentsDAO multipleStudentDAO = ... 
request.setAttribute("studentDAO", multipleStudentDAO);
```

You then don't need to specify the scope in the tag and can just do this:

```
<display:table export="true" id="data"
        name="studentDAO.studentList"
        requestURI="/mssrv.do" pagesize="5">
```